# The parameterized query *** which was not supplied

Tags: c#, database, prepared-statement

I'm getting an error

> The parameterized query '(@MuscleId int,@FitnessId nvarchar(4000))SELECT ExerciseId, Naam' expects the parameter '@FitnessId', which was not supplied.

I tried to fix it with `parameter.Value = DBNull.Value`. But I still get the same error, because I'm probably doing it wrong.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

(`MGX.MuscleId` and `X.FitnessId` are both set to int)

Code:

```
private void Exercises()
{
    string query = "SELECT ExerciseId, Naam FROM Xercises AS X " +
            "INNER JOIN MG_Exercise AS MGX ON MGX.ExerciseId = X.ExerciseId " +
            "WHERE MGX.MuscleId = @MuscleId AND X.FitnessId = @FitnessId";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MuscleId", comBoxMuscleGroup.SelectedValue);
        SqlParameter param2 = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FitnessId", comBoxTypeFitness.SelectedValue);

        if (param.Value == null)
        {
            param.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        if (param2.Value == null)
        {
            param2.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        DataTable Xdata = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(Xdata);    *****ERROR*****

        clbXcercises.DisplayMember = "Naam";
        clbXcercises.ValueMember = "ExerciseId";
        clbXcercises.DataSource = Xdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(param == null)`: you mean `if(param.Value == null)`, right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that...I edited it.

Comment: In the second if you set the value to the first parameter

Comment: So what is your actual code?

Comment: I edited it right now, thanks. But now it gives an error saying: 'Ambiguous column name 'ExerciseId'.' at the same spot.

Comment: I guess you have that column multiple times due to the joins. Use `x.ExerciseId`.

Comment: You have set the ALIAS to X now you should reference your fields with X.ExerciseID, X.Naam to avoid ambiguities with fields having the same name but present in tables used by the JOIN

Comment: Thanks guys! :D I didn't know aliases worked before they were called out.

Comment: Unrelated but worth mentioning: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)